# How to pass the SSO page using Uptime -kuma?

Tags: single-sign-on, network-monitoring, uptime-monitoring, uptime-kuma

I have set up uptime kuma to monitor few websites. ow there is a website which is reachable only through SSO , when done manually. When I try to monitor this website , it is not able to give me correct status . How to pass through this page using uptime kuma and get the correct status ?

Answer (score 0):

With http monitor, try to find a public ressource as a target eg. yoursite.com/favicon.ico or something similar

If not possible and as long as your uptime kuma server is publicly accessible, you'll have to do it with a push monitor, check [this github issue](https://github.com/louislam/uptime-kuma/issues/279)

Answer (score 0):

uptime-kuma HTTP(s) monitoring type supports basic auth and NTLM authentication.

If that does not work. You will have to setup a heartbeat monitor... basically the webapp will push heartbeat to uptime-kuma:

Add new monitor then select "push" in the monitor type menu as in this screenshot:

[image]

The webapp behind the SSO should make a GET request the push url every n seconds as set in the heartbeat interval for this monitor.

See more here:

https://github.com/louislam/uptime-kuma/issues/279

https://github.com/louislam/uptime-kuma/issues/558